# Log transformation for lm() in R not working

Tags: r, linear-regression, anova

I am trying to transform some data so that the assumptions of linear models (independence, linearity, homogeneity of variance, normality) are met. I want to do this so that I can perform an ANOVA or similar. Square root transforming the response variable within my linear model has worked, but an error appears when I try to log transform.

I have tried:
`logCC_emergent_biomass.lm <- lm(log(Total_CC_noAcari_Biomass)~ Dungfauna*Water*Earthworms, data= biomass)`

But this error appears:
`Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'`

Normally log transforming in this way works for me so I am not sure what is wrong here. The data of the response variable is all decimal data (e.g. 0.001480370), potentially this is the cause? If this is the case can anyone point me in the direction of how I can transform this data.

This is these are residuals plots when the data is untransformed:
[image]

Comment: Do you have zero values in `Total_CC_noAcari_Biomass`?

Comment: Please note my updated answer, I made a mistake, it's actually `log1p(X1)`, not `log1p(X1 + 1)`, since `log1p(X1)` translates to `log(X1 + 1)`. Also see link to a great post on _Cross Validated_ I've added. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have zeroes in the variable you want to log transform. *Example:*

```
df1[1, 1] <- 0

lm(Y ~ log(X1) + X2 + X3, df1)
# Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
#   NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
# In addition: Warning message:
#   In log(X1) : NaNs produced
```

You could consider `log1p` which calculates `log(x + 1)`.

```
lm(Y ~ log1p(X1) + X2 + X3, df1)
# Call:
# lm(formula = Y ~ log1p(X1) + X2 + X3, data = df1)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)    log1p(X1)           X2           X3
#        0.9963      -0.8648       0.5293       1.0904
```

However, this changes the interpretation, see [related post on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160021/interpretation-of-log1-x-transformed-predictor). Anyway, you should decide what to do with the zero values.

Also see this post: [*How should I transform non-negative data including zeros?*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/how-should-i-transform-non-negative-data-including-zeros)

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- structure(list(X1 = c(0, -0.564698171396089, 0.363128411337339, 
0.63286260496104, 0.404268323140999, -0.106124516091484, 1.51152199743894, 
-0.0946590384130976, 2.01842371387704, -0.062714099052421), X2 = c(1.30486965422349, 
2.28664539270111, -1.38886070111234, -0.278788766817371, -0.133321336393658, 
0.635950398070074, -0.284252921416072, -2.65645542090478, -2.44046692857552, 
1.32011334573019), X3 = c(-0.306638594078475, -1.78130843398, 
-0.171917355759621, 1.2146746991726, 1.89519346126497, -0.4304691316062, 
-0.25726938276893, -1.76316308519478, 0.460097354831271, -0.639994875960119
), Y = c(2.00627879909717, 1.08150911284604, 1.41465103918476, 
1.37787039819613, 3.04863502238068, -0.828228728348569, 0.198328716326719, 
-2.34295203837687, -1.61863179473641, 1.03962922460575)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```